# Usar $lookup para exportar información de unas colecciones en mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, csv, join

Tengo un problema al querer exportar los resultados de un `$lookup`, para realizar el export usando mongoexport pero aún no puedo lograrlo, alguien que vea qué estoy haciendo mal o alguna equivalencia para obtener un CSV a partir del JOIN de Colecciones?

```
./mongoexport --host=127.0.0.1:27017 --db=PruebaDB --collection=collectionPrueba --query '{"$lookup":{"from":"collectionOrigen","localField":"local_id","foreignField":"foraneo_id","as":"salida"}}' --type csv --quiet -out salida.txt
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
Failed: unknown top level operator: $lookup
```

Posterior quiero ocupar un `unwind` y todo lo que sea pero quisiera primero hacer que se ejecute.

Comment: Algún error en concreto?

Comment: Failed: unknown top level operator: $lookup

Answer (score 1):

Tomé de base un post que encontré aquí mismo, lo pongo por si alguien lo ocupa:

Crear un archivo que contenga la información que se quiere obtener:

```
db.export_collectionAux.drop();

cursor = db.collectionOrigen.aggregate({$lookup:{from:"collectionJoin",localField:"origen_id",foreignField:"join_Id",as:"salida"}},{$unwind:"$salida"},{"$project":{"_id":0,"campo_aux":1,"salida.campo_join":1}})

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
doc = cursor.next();

    db.export_collectionAux.insert(doc);
}
```

Ejecuta creando la colección:

```
mongo host:port/DB archivo.txt
```

Vacia el archivo en un csv:

```
mongoexport --host=host:port --db=DB --collection=export_collectionAux --fields campo1,salida.campo1 --type csv --out outputfile.txt --quiet
```

Comment: ¿Como se ejecuta eso desde node ?